# Why numerical integration gives error with argument substitution

Tags: numerical-integration

I define function

```
g[x_] := NIntegrate[Tanh[x y]/(y^2 + 1), {y, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

`g[1] = 1.04826`. But `g[x]/.{x->1}` gives error: `NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand Tanh[x y]/(1+y^2) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],0.}}`. I use this function in another numerical integration and obtain the same error. How to avoid this problem?

Comment: Since the definition of `g` uses numeric techniques, its arguments should be restricted to numeric values: `g[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Tanh[x y]/(y^2 + 1), {y, 0, Infinity}]`

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037